# pub build fails due to urlencoded version numbers

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

Pub build  throws the following error

```
Resolving dependencies...
Error on line 1, column 1 of  
https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/source_maps/versions/0.10.0%2B2:
Invalid version constraint: Could not parse version
```

It seems pub tries to update https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/source_maps version to 0.10.0+2. The url contains version number and its encoded from **+** sign to **%2B**.

pub version 1.6.0,
OS Fedora 19, Any ways to overcome this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Can you please report at http://dartbug.com ? I think I have seen something similar recently. I guess you are using Windows?

Comment: OS Fedora 19, Just tried Ubuntu 14.04 also, got the same error. No idea on Windows.
To reproduce in an existing project try removing pup-cache and also the pubspeck.lock file and build freshly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pub version 1.6.0 didn't yet support the `+` in version constraints.
You need to update to a newer version.

Comment: Yes the answer from dartbug.com to update 1.9.1
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=23061